# An alternative to Tor

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, censorship, troubleshooting

In our college, Tor is not functioning. I've tried many other proxy sites like (say, [hide my ass](http://hidemyass.com/)). These sites have also been blocked. Can any one suggest an alternative?

Comment: Have you try the Tor bridges? Or if Tor doesn't work try with I2P network or Freenet. They are p2p anonymous network

Comment: You maybe able to use Pluggable Transposts version of TBB

Comment: As it stands, this question is generating a lot of speculative and low quality answers. Can you please provide more information so that we can help you get Tor working, and reword the question to be about how/why tor is blocked at your university? Thanks. For more info see "[How do I ask a good question?](http://tor.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)" in the help center.

Comment: You may try JAP(JonDonym). It will probably work for you. However, the free version of JAP is slow. The paid version of JonDonym is much faster.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that your university is blocking most outbound ports.  After opening the Tor Browser Bundle, click Settings, click the Network tab in the Settings window, and check the box `My firewall only lets me connect to certain ports`.  (The default Allowed Ports 80 and 443 should work.)

Comment: You may also have to restart the Tor Browser Bundle for the settings to take effect.

Comment: Sorry I have tried every thing it is not working still....

Comment: You need to give me something to work with...what exactly do you mean it isn't working?  Can you verify that your installation of Tor is working by connecting successfully from somewhere else?